# Windows command line to run as the currently logged in user after starting command/batch script as another user within the same script?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, powershell, runas

I have a Windows batch script which is auto run at login as a particular admin user (not the same user that is logged in) for all standard users.

Within the same script, I need to run a check on their group membership *(by calling an exe with a specific group as a parameter)* on the currently logged in user, *i.e. the user who is logged into windows which the script's shell displays and is run from/on*.

Then dependant on the outcome of the aforementioned check, continue processing the same script using the initial admin user's rights, *i.e. to install software.*

Is there any way to do this **without asking for credentials**, purely through command line or maybe even powershell *(called from within the script)*?

I'm looking for a completely non-interactive experience for the user as this is to be applied to up to approx. 9000 users.

Any help would be appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: See [Command line argument for running as another user on Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/232899/command-line-argument-for-running-as-another-user-on-windows?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

`Runas` command has key `/savedсred`, **but** under every new user you still need to enter the password(once).

There is way in powershell:

1. Use [ConvertTo-SecureStrin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.security/convertto-securestring)g to encrypt password
2. Create [credentials](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/system.management.automation.pscredential) object
3. Run application with [Start-Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process)

`$secstring = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force`

`$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList @($username,$secstring)`

`Start-Process <filefullpath> -WorkingDirectory <work dir> -Credential ($credentials)`

**But** securestring encrypted on a computer can not be decrypted at the other ([if you do not encrypt with a known key with -Key parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15580523/powershell-secure-password-to-work-on-any-machine)) In fact, you have to put credentials in the body of your script.